# Is ${(k^n)}^{\otimes r}$ a faithful $k\Sigma_r$-module for $n\geq r$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, representation-theory

I have the following question:

Let $k$ be an infinite field. Let $E:={(k^n)}^{\otimes r}$ and let the symmetric group $\Sigma_r$ act
from the right on $E$ by place permutations. It is well-known that the group algebra $k\Sigma_r$ is a selfinjective algebra.

> Is it true that $E$ is a faithful $k\Sigma_r$-module for $n \geq r$ (and why?), but not in general for $n<r$ (and why) ?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: When $n \geq r$ it is faithful because it contains a copy of the regular representation: pick a basis $e_1, \ldots, e_n$ of $k^n$ and send $\sigma \in \Sigma_r$ to $e_{\sigma(1)} \otimes \cdots \otimes e_{\sigma(r)}$.